# Executed a Stored Procedure in the Production Server and the following warning message is shown

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures

I executed a stored procedure on the production server; and though it shows that query has been successfully completed it doesn't allow me to close SQL Server Management Studio and the below warning message is shown. Please advice I'm more concerned because this is the production server.

[image: Query_Window]

[image: Close SSM]

Comment: It seems like a transaction was started but not committed. Were you running previous queries with begin transaction?

Comment: Looks to me like `GenActiveItemPriceList` might be poorly written.  Or perhaps you ran some code prior to what you show on screen that ran `BEGIN TRANSACTION` without having a `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT` clause.  On another note, why would you run this seemingly strange code against a production server without knowing the outcome?

Comment: @MaxVernon I actually performed some manual updates to the Price-list table & this SP had to be executed after my manual update what it actually does is that there is a column as (IsActive) and it updates either (0 OR 1)Based on the Active dates of the Price-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are closing SSMS, it check for

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Or you can use [sys.dm_exec_requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx)

```
SELECT open_transaction_count FROM sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE session_id = @SessionId
```

In this case you have an open transaction so on connection closure process SQL Server will roll back that transaction. In this case you need to take a look at the stored procdure `dbo.GenActiveItemPriceList` and identify what is this transaction is which is not commited and it's furter impact.